# Borrow from American 401k from Canada

Tags: united-states, loans, 401k

If I have a 401k with (for the sake of argument) $100,000 in the US, and I want to **borrow** the maximum ($50,000) for a mortgage on a house in Canada, is this possible?

If so, what are some of the problems I should consider?

Edit: I mistakenly wrote "withdraw" instead of "borrow"

Comment: you can always take money out (for whatever reason) as long as you mind any penalty or fees associated with it. The intent of the withdrawal is secondary and shouldn't factor really.

Comment: Would this be a loan from the 401(k), or a withdrawal?  Are you retirement age?  Are you still employed at the company that holds the 401(k)?

Comment: Sorry I put withdraw but I meant borrow - hopefully the question makes more sense now.

Comment: You can, but read the answers and comments [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/56793/would-it-be-advantageous-for-me-to-pay-off-these-two-credit-cards-and-cancel-the) about borrowing from a 401k.

Comment: **Loans** from 401(k) plans have to be **paid back**; else they become _withdrawals_  which will incur penalties etc if you are young. Also, if you are not currently employed by the sponsor of the 401(k) plan where you hold 100K, are you sure that that you can _get_ a 401(k) loan? Finally, if you need to get 50K for a downpayment on a house and so have mortgage payments to make, how on earth are you going to _pay back_ that 401(k) loan?

Comment: Well it seems more desirable to pay myself the interest than the bank, where that money is essentially lost. If I no-longer work for that company, am I not able to take a loan from the 401k?

Comment: "If I no-longer work for that company, am I not able to take a loan from the 401k?" Call your ex-HR Department but don't be surprised if the answer is No. You no longer work for them; why should they be interested in obliging you?

Answer (score 5):

Can't comment yet, but typically 401(k) loans are paid back through payroll deductions. If you no longer work for the company than you have no payroll to deduct from. The loan provisions are stipulated in the adoption agreement for your plan.